# cross-references for previous lemmas and theorems

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, theorems

I'm new with LaTeX and I'm having trouble with the enumeration given when I cross-reference, It doesn't match the one given by the section.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\author{My name}
\title{Title}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter*{Introducción}

\chapter{Conceptos preliminares}

\newtheorem{cont}[section]{Definición}
\begin{cont}
def
\end{cont}

\chapter{The Theorem}
\newtheorem{ext}[section]{Definición}
\begin{ext}
def
\end{ext}

\newtheorem{clocc}[section]{Definición}
\begin{clocc}
def
\end{clocc}

\newtheorem{tm}[section]{Teorema}
\begin{tm}
thrm
\begin{proof}
proof
\end{proof}
\end{tm}

\newtheorem{arcoord}[section]{Definición}
\begin{arcoord}
def
\end{arcoord}

\newtheorem{l1}[section]{Lema}
\begin{l1}
lemma \label{l1}
\begin{proof}
proof
\end{proof}
\end{l1}

\newtheorem{l4}[section]{Lema}
\begin{l4}
lemma
\begin{proof}
Lema \ref{l1}
\end{proof}
\end{l4}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Apparently you have misunderstood `newtheorem` completely. You don't need to use `\newtheorem` over and over again!

Comment: I think I misunderstood many things. ¿How do you use it properly?

Comment: See the possible answer and the screenshot

Comment: For a general introduction to theorem environments http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/LaTeXPrimer/Theorems.html and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems could be helpful. For general introduction to labels and cross references see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing

Comment: @WillieWong How do you make it look good when you edit?

Comment: Please visit the help center. http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the 'usefulness' of using numbers as part of the environment name (or using `l1` as label name), there are some issues here:

- Just use one `\newtheorem` for each theorem type, i.e. a `Lema` or a `Theorem` or `Example` etc.
- Reusing `\newtheorem` for each new lema would lead to environments all being numbered as `1` or `1.1`, etc. -- this is awkward.
- I don't think that `section` should be a shared counter here, but the resetting counter, i.e. `[section]` belongs to end of the theorem definition, not in between (but this is a guess only)
- `\ref` without a previous label won't work (apart from giving `?` as output!`, i.e. the`\label{l1}` must be specified before!

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{l1}{Lema}[section]

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}

\begin{l1}
  This is a lemma. \label{l1}
\end{l1}
\begin{proof}
   The proof is left to the reader
\end{proof}


\begin{l1}
  This is another lemma.
\end{l1}
\begin{proof}
    The result follows from Lemma \ref{l1}.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The label is working fine now, though I still don't understand the "newtheorem" proper usage.

Comment: I edited my question trying to post only a "skeleton" of my work to see where I'm going wrong

Comment: @ElDinosaurio: As I told you already: You don't need to define a `\newtheorem` for each `Defnicion` etc. The definition is exactly meant to have them available at any place later on. You need different `\newtheorem` calls for different types only, i.e. `Lema`, `Definicion` etc. Ideally, ,`\newtheorem` should be used in the preamble only